# Functional Square Root of Piecewise Functions

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition, piecewise-continuity, involutions, fractional-iteration

> Let $s:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be the function defined as
>   $$s(x)=x+(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$$
>   Find a function $t:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $t^{\circ 2}=s$, or prove that no such function exists.

I was fairly sure that I could construct such a function $t$ by taking multiple cases and defining it as a piecewise function. I started by expressing $s$ as a piecewise function:
$$ s\left(x\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x+1 & : \lfloor x\rfloor \operatorname{even}\\
       x-1 & : \lfloor x\rfloor \operatorname{odd}
     \end{array}
   \right.\\$$
This gave me the idea of trying to construct $t$ as a piecewise function. And since $s$ depended on parity, I decided to construct $t$ according to the remainder of $x$ modulo $4$.

Through a bit of trial and error, I figured out that this wouldn't work, so I tried modulo $3$, which also didn't work. I eventually came up with the following, based on remainders modulo $5$:
$$ t\left(x\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x+2 & : \lfloor x\rfloor \equiv 0 \pmod 5\\
       x+2 & : \lfloor x\rfloor \equiv 1 \pmod 5\\
       x-1 & : \lfloor x\rfloor \equiv 2 \pmod 5\\
       x-3 & : \lfloor x\rfloor \equiv 3 \pmod 5\\
       x+4 & : \lfloor x\rfloor \equiv 3 \pmod 5\\
     \end{array}
   \right.\\$$

Anyways, that question took way too long to solve (too much trial and error). Are there any general methods for constructing half-iterates of piecewise functions, without resorting to trial and error? It would be very helpful to know how I should attack this kind of problem.

For example, suppose I wanted to find the functional square root of
$$ f\left(x\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x+5 & : -\infty\lt x\le -5 \\
       1-2x & : -5\lt x\le 1\\
       4x-4 & : 1\lt x\le \infty\\
     \end{array}
   \right.\\$$
How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $t^{\circ 4}=s^{\circ 2}=\operatorname{id}$. While $s$ maps $0+\epsilon\mapsto 1+\epsilon\mapsto 0+\epsilon$ and $2+\epsilon\mapsto 3+\epsilon\mapsto 2+\epsilon$, we can simply let $t$ map $0+\epsilon\mapsto2+\epsilon\mapsto1+\epsilon\mapsto3+\epsilon\mapsto0+\epsilon$. Simply extend this pattern, i.e.

$$t(x)=\begin{cases}x+2&\text{if }\lfloor x\rfloor\equiv 0\pmod 4\\
x+2&\text{if }\lfloor x\rfloor\equiv 1\pmod 4\\
x-1&\text{if }\lfloor x\rfloor\equiv 2\pmod 4\\
x-3&\text{if }\lfloor x\rfloor\equiv 3\pmod 4
\end{cases} $$

Comment: This can't be right. If $s$ is an involution, then so is $2s(x/2)$, making $t$ an involution, and thus not the half-iterate of $s$.

Comment: @Nilknarf Indeed, I mistranslated the pattern